# Logging into Cortana changed my windows login password

Tags: windows-10, authentication

I had a user account on Windows 10, with a short password because I'm the only user, and then I logged into Cortana with my email account... then I locked my computer -- to log back in my user profile changed from 'Patrick' to my email address, and to get into the computer I was forced to type in my Microsoft Account password instead of my normal windows password.

How can I go back to normal user profile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, that's because setting up Cortana implies associating your Microsoft account with the local one in your computer.

To undo this, you have to go to **Settings**:

[image: Entering Settings]

Then enter the **Accounts** section:

[image: Entering Accounts section]

And, in **Your Account**, choose **"Sign in with a local account instead"**.

[image: "Your Account" menu]

You'll have to enter your credentials, and then you'll be all set!

*(Pictures from [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/))*